# C - How to actually use a long long datatype with the ctime function

Tags: c, long-integer, c99, ctime, long-long

I tried asking this before but I forgot to include a question (since I just joined the site), so I didn't actually have my problem solved, people just told me why the second bit of code was wrong instead of how to make it work. This is part of a homework assignment. The purpose of which is to eventually put INT_MAX+1 into ctime to prove the point that in a 32bit machine the date cannot pass ~2038 because it runs out of bits for the number of seconds since 1970. My question simply is how can I put a long long into ctime? How can I make the second bit of code work?

All is compiled in C99, if that matters.

Works:

```
    long x = INT_MAX-1;
    printf("Time: %s",ctime(&x));
```

Doesn't Work:

```
    long long x = INT_MAX+1;
    printf("Time: %s",ctime(&x));
```

Error:

```
incompatible pointer type: "Expected 'const time_t *' but argument is of type 'long long int *'"
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [C - How to use a long long with ctime (C99)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14534633/c-how-to-use-a-long-long-with-ctime-c99)

Comment: You are not doing your homework. Pun intended.

Comment: I'm not aware of an O/S that uses an epoch in 1975.  The Unix epoch is 1970-01-01 00:00:00 +00:00.  You cannot pass a `long long *` to `ctime()` without incurring undefined behaviour; it expects a `time_t *`.  The question is insoluble on 32-bit machines where INT_MAX == LONG_MAX and INT_MAX + 1 is undefined (because signed overflow leads to undefined behaviour).  What your classwork is probably asking is for you to use a `time_t` value, set it to `INT_MAX`, add one and hope it wraps (not guaranteed), and then print out its value and what you get from `ctime()`, which should be a date in 1901.

Comment: shf301, that was the question I asked that did not get answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.  You are on a system that uses a 32 bit `time_t` value.  Passing a 64 bit `long long` will gives you an error because it doesn't work.